# S3 DeleteObject Policy does not adding and PHP deleteObject SDK not working

Tags: amazon-s3

I tried the codes shared by Amazon to delete the objects in S3, but it didn't work. I can't catch any error messages from the Try Catch build. Also, I can't add the Delete Object action to the S3 Bucket Policy, it throws an error. You can find the error attached.

[image]